# Address used by a function pointer

Tags: c, function-pointers, x86-64, disassembly

This question has to do with a college assignment, so I'll keep it abstract to not give away any part of the challenge.

Given a compiled C program (x86_64 ELF on Linux), is there a way to know, just from the disassembly, which address a function pointer inside of that program would contain to point to a specific function (also inside of the program, not an external library) in any execution of the program? Is it possible to infer the complete address just from the address of that function in the disassembly?

For example, if the program contains a pointer: `void (*ptr) () = &someFunc;`, is the content of ptr inferable from the adress of someFunc in the disassembly?

Comment: "so I'll keep it abstract to not give away any part of the challenge." I am going to give you the benefit of the doubt and interpret that as *You don't want us to answer the full assignment*, but it can also be interpreted as *You don't want to get caught posting a question about your assignment*

Comment: @bolov thank you, it is definetly the former, the full assignment is much more complex than this, and I have mostly solved it.

Comment: your question is a bit unclear. Give a *for instance*

Comment: Have you checked for a jump in the relative addresses?

Comment: my gut says 'no' for the general case. But for specific cases (known OS, compiler, linker, loader, ...) it might be possible. Especially in embedded cases where the loader and memory layouts are very primitive. However I would be interested to be shown to be wrong

Comment: So the calls and jumps with immediates use the relative addresses (3 bytes long), but the calls to content of variables use 8bytes...

Comment: for data , in general everything is relative to various base registers that point a data segment , stack etc.The linker / loader pair arrange for the base registers to be set at load time. For code, jumps are relative, function calls typically are absolute but again they are fixed up at link / load time

Comment: I am not sure I am understanding your question correctly. In a terms of disassembly, operation `void (*ptr) () = &someFunc;` would be similar to `ptr = someconstant` or `ptr = somerelativeconstanttosomething` and that constant would represent address. If you are just abusing function pointers for no use, you may not see them at all at disassembly (no variable `ptr` has ever existed) and then your question would be about nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to solved the problem. As it turned out, the addresses the function pointers were using were the exact addresses in the disassembly. At the end I figured it out stepping through with gdb and looking at the contents of the registers.

Comment: Yup, this is true in general on almost all CPU architectures.  A few (like ARM) use the low bit of the pointer to indicate ARM-mode vs. Thumb2 mode (because ARM and Thumb instructions always have to be at least 2-byte aligned, the low bit can be re-purposed).  It's still the actual address used for a jump / call instruction, but on ARM `blx reg` will switch modes if needed depending on the low bit of the pointer in a register.  See https://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/beginner-s-corner/4024632/Introduction-to-ARM-thumb.